# Create a wav. file from a MIDI file and serving it to NWEB

Tags: c, server, wav, midi

I'm trying to add a feature to nweb which allows it to render MIDI .mid files into .wav sound files so that a browser such as Chrome with a built-in .wav player can play them. I have the nweb but other than that I'm completely stumped. Help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <signal.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

#define BUFSIZE 8096 
#define ERROR 42 
#define SORRY 43 
#define LOG   44 

struct { 
    char *ext; 
    char *filetype; 
} extensions [] = { 
    {"gif", "image/gif" },   
    {"jpg", "image/jpeg"},  
    {"jpeg","image/jpeg"}, 
    {"png", "image/png" },   
    {"zip", "image/zip" },   
    {"gz",  "image/gz"  },   
    {"tar", "image/tar" },   
    {"htm", "text/html" },   
    {"html","text/html" },   
    {"mp3","music/mp3"}, 
    {0,0} }; 

void log(int type, char *s1, char *s2, int num) 
{ 
int fd ; 
char logbuffer[BUFSIZE*2]; 

switch (type) { 
case ERROR: (void)sprintf(logbuffer,"ERROR: %s:%s Errno=%d exiting pid=%d",s1, s2, errno,getpid()); break; 
case SORRY:  
    (void)sprintf(logbuffer, "<HTML><BODY><H1>nweb Web Server Sorry: %s %s</H1></BODY></HTML>\r\n", s1, s2); 
    (void)write(num,logbuffer,strlen(logbuffer)); 
    (void)sprintf(logbuffer,"SORRY: %s:%s",s1, s2);  
    break; 
case LOG: (void)sprintf(logbuffer," INFO: %s:%s:%d",s1, s2,num); break; 
}     
/* no checks here, nothing can be done a failure anyway */ 
if((fd = open("nweb.log", O_CREAT| O_WRONLY | O_APPEND,0644)) >= 0) { 
    (void)write(fd,logbuffer,strlen(logbuffer));  
    (void)write(fd,"\n",1);       
    (void)close(fd); 
} 
if(type == ERROR || type == SORRY) exit(3); 
} 

/* this is a child web server process, so we can exit on errors */ 
void web(int fd, int hit) 
{ 
int j, file_fd, buflen, len; 
long i, ret; 
char * fstr; 
static char buffer[BUFSIZE+1]; /* static so zero filled */ 

ret =read(fd,buffer,BUFSIZE);     /* read Web request in one go */ 
if(ret == 0 || ret == -1) {    /* read failure stop now */ 
    log(SORRY,"failed to read browser request","",fd); 
} 
if(ret > 0 && ret < BUFSIZE)    /* return code is valid chars */ 
    buffer[ret]=0;        /* terminate the buffer */ 
else buffer[0]=0; 

for(i=0;i<ret;i++)    /* remove CF and LF characters */ 
    if(buffer[i] == '\r' || buffer[i] == '\n') 
        buffer[i]='*'; 
log(LOG,"request",buffer,hit); 

if( strncmp(buffer,"GET ",4) && strncmp(buffer,"get ",4) ) 
    log(SORRY,"Only simple GET operation supported",buffer,fd); 

for(i=4;i<BUFSIZE;i++) { /* null terminate after the second space to ignore extra stuff */ 
    if(buffer[i] == ' ') { /* string is "GET URL " +lots of other stuff */ 
        buffer[i] = 0; 
        break; 
    } 
} 

for(j=0;j<i-1;j++)     /* check for illegal parent directory use .. */ 
    if(buffer[j] == '.' && buffer[j+1] == '.') 
        log(SORRY,"Parent directory (..) path names not supported",buffer,fd); 

if( !strncmp(&buffer[0],"GET /\0",6) || !strncmp(&buffer[0],"get /\0",6) ) /* convert no filename to index file */ 
    (void)strcpy(buffer,"GET /index.html"); 

/* work out the file type and check we support it */ 
buflen=strlen(buffer); 
fstr = (char *)0; 
for(i=0;extensions[i].ext != 0;i++) { 
    len = strlen(extensions[i].ext); 
    if( !strncmp(&buffer[buflen-len], extensions[i].ext, len)) { 
        fstr =extensions[i].filetype; 
        break; 
    } 
} 
if(fstr == 0) log(SORRY,"file extension type not supported",buffer,fd); 

if(( file_fd = open(&buffer[5],O_RDONLY)) == -1) /* open the file for reading */ 
    log(SORRY, "failed to open file",&buffer[5],fd); 

log(LOG,"SEND",&buffer[5],hit); 

(void)sprintf(buffer,"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: %s\r\n\r\n", fstr); 
(void)write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer)); 

/* send file in 8KB block - last block may be smaller */ 
while (    (ret = read(file_fd, buffer, BUFSIZE)) > 0 ) { 
    (void)write(fd,buffer,ret); 
} 
#ifdef LINUX 
sleep(1);    /* to allow socket to drain */ 
#endif 
exit(1); 
} 


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
int i, port, pid, listenfd, socketfd, hit; 
size_t length; 
static struct sockaddr_in cli_addr; /* static = initialised to zeros */ 
static struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; /* static = initialised to zeros */ 

if( argc < 3  || argc > 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-?") ) { 
    (void)printf("hint: nweb Port-Number Top-Directory\n\n" 
"\tnweb is a small and very safe mini web server\n" 
"\tnweb only servers out file/web pages with extensions named below\n" 
"\t and only from the named directory or its sub-directories.\n" 
"\tThere is no fancy features = safe and secure.\n\n" 
"\tExample: nweb 8181 /home/nwebdir &\n\n" 
"\tOnly Supports:"); 
    for(i=0;extensions[i].ext != 0;i++) 
        (void)printf(" %s",extensions[i].ext); 

    (void)printf("\n\tNot Supported: URLs including \"..\", Java, Javascript, CGI\n" 
"\tNot Supported: directories / /etc /bin /lib /tmp /usr /dev /sbin \n" 
"\tNo warranty given or implied\n\tNigel Griffiths nag@uk.ibm.com\n" 
        ); 
    exit(0); 
} 
if( !strncmp(argv[2],"/"   ,2 ) || !strncmp(argv[2],"/etc", 5 ) || 
    !strncmp(argv[2],"/bin",5 ) || !strncmp(argv[2],"/lib", 5 ) || 
    !strncmp(argv[2],"/tmp",5 ) || !strncmp(argv[2],"/usr", 5 ) || 
    !strncmp(argv[2],"/dev",5 ) || !strncmp(argv[2],"/sbin",6) ){ 
    (void)printf("ERROR: Bad top directory %s, see nweb -?\n",argv[2]); 
    exit(3); 
} 
if(chdir(argv[2]) == -1){  
    (void)printf("ERROR: Can't Change to directory %s\n",argv[2]); 
    exit(4); 
} 

/* Become daemon + unstoppable and no zombies children (= no wait()) */ 
if(fork() != 0) 
    return 0; /* parent returns OK to shell */ 
(void)signal(SIGCLD, SIG_IGN); /* ignore child death */ 
(void)signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN); /* ignore terminal hangups */ 
for(i=0;i<32;i++) 
    (void)close(i);        /* close open files */ 
(void)setpgrp();        /* break away from process group */ 

log(LOG,"nweb starting",argv[1],getpid()); 
/* setup the network socket */ 
if((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0)) <0) 
    log(ERROR, "system call","socket",0); 
port = atoi(argv[1]); 
if(port < 0 || port >60000) 
    log(ERROR,"Invalid port number (try 1->60000)",argv[1],0); 
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port); 
if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) <0) 
    log(ERROR,"system call","bind",0); 
if( listen(listenfd,64) <0) 
    log(ERROR,"system call","listen",0); 

for(hit=1; ;hit++) { 
    length = sizeof(cli_addr); 
    if((socketfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &length)) < 0) 
        log(ERROR,"system call","accept",0); 

    if((pid = fork()) < 0) { 
        log(ERROR,"system call","fork",0); 
    } 
    else { 
        if(pid == 0) {     /* child */ 
            (void)close(listenfd); 
            web(socketfd,hit); /* never returns */ 
        } else {     /* parent */ 
            (void)close(socketfd); 
        } 
    } 
} 
}
```

Comment: Chrome and Firefox browsers both have MIDI player plugins available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FluidSynth (http://www.fluidsynth.org/). It comes with a C library. The API is documented here:

http://fluidsynth.sourceforge.net/api/

You can render a MIDI file with something like:

```
#include <fluidsynth.h>

// ...

fluid_settings_t* settings = new_fluid_settings()
// Render at 44.1KHz.
fluid_settings_setnum(settings, "synth.sample-rate", 44100);
fluid_synth_t* synth = new_fluid_synth(settings)
// Set volume to 70%. High volume levels may cause clipping.
fluid_synth_set_gain(synth, 0.7f);
// Quality of interpolation. This is high quality. Needs more CPU.
fluid_synth_set_interp_method(synth, -1, FLUID_INTERP_7THORDER);
// Which soundfont file to use.
fluid_synth_sfload(synth, "soundfont.sf2", true);
fluid_player_t* player = new_fluid_player(synth);
// Load a MIDI file.
fluid_player_add(player, "midi_file.mid");
// Start "playing" the MIDI file. This simply prepares the file for
// rendering, it doesn't really "play" anything.
fluid_player_play(player);
```

Note: instead of `fluid_player_add()`, you can use `fluid_player_add_mem()` instead to feed MIDI bytes to FluidSynth. This depends on how you get your MIDI data from your source.

The above initializes and sets up a synth and a player. Note that you need a soundfont file (in SF2 format), otherwise you can't render anything. SF2 files contain audio data for the various MIDI instruments. Assuming your MIDI files are targeting the GM standard (General MIDI), you will need to find a GM soundfont (or a GS one; GS is an extension of GM with more instruments, some MIDI files need that.) There many free SF2 soundfonts available, with varying sizes (ranging anywhere between 2MB and several GB.)

To actually do rendering and get audio data back, you make calls to `fluid_synth_write_float()` (for floating point samples) or `fluid_synth_write_s16()` (for integer samples). After that, check whether the MIDI files has ended playing with `fluid_player_get_status()`.

Once you get the audio samples, you can either serve them in WAV format, or use an encoder (like the libvorbisfile library) to compress the samples into Ogg/Vorbis audio. Or maybe with libmpg123 to serve MP3 audio instead.